# How to trace at runtime(flex)

Tags: apache-flex

How to see traces at the console or some window the trace messages from the application?

or save the traces in some file, but I can't find the trace file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use external libraries such as Olog. Some of the debug libraries found [here](http://www.as3gamegears.com/category/debug/) provide UI consoles above your application. This way, you can easily log and see traces while running the application.

I would recommend trying Olog and MonsterDebugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Vizzy on the PC and FlashTrace on the Mac.

As long as your running the debug layer the traces will kick out to those apps.